# v7.widget.SearchView is no longer valid

Tags: android, widget, toolbar, searchview

I have this xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

but there is a problem in (v7.widget.SearchView)it is not working, and in inspection
results it show(v7.widget.SearchView) no longer valid.
can someone help me in this problem?(and sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

as you said `v7.widget.SearchView` is no longer valid, so you have to use the updated version of it `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`